# Data storage approach for different file types

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, entity-framework, dataset

Currently I'm working on an application to import data from different sources (csv and xml). The core data in the files are the same (ID, Name, Coordinate, etc.) but with different structures (xml: in nodes, tables: on rows) and in the xml I have additional data which I need to keep together till the export. Additionally important to say, I need for the visualization and modification just a few data but I need all for the export.

[image]

**Problem:**
I'm locking for a good structure (database or what ever) where I can import the data at run-time. I need to have a reference to the data to visualize and modify them. Afterward I need to export the information to a user specified file type.  (consider the image).

**Approaches:**

1. I defined a class for the csv schema and mapped the necessary information of the xml to it. The problem occurs when I try to export the data because I have not all data available in the memory.
2. I defined a class for the xml schema and mapped the information from the csv to it. The problem is in this case, that the storage structure bases on the schema of the xml and if this xml schema changes, I need to change the whole storage structure.
3. I'm planing now to implement a sql database with entity framework. This is not the easiest way but it seems to be state-of-the-art and updateable. The thing is that I'm not very experienced with databases and the entity framework. That's way I like to know whether this is a good way to solve this problem.

Last thing to say: I would like to store the imported data just once and would like to work with references to this source. This way I can export the information from this source and I'm certain that I have the current data.

**Question:**
What is the common way to solve such storage problems. Did I missed a good approach? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is called ETL - Extract_Transform_Load. Read about SSIS - SQL Server Integration Services. That's one tool for it.

Comment: This sounds really interesting and goes for sure in the right direction. Thank you!